# Dynamically changing the Image source for HTML,JSON

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to make some CSS cards using JSON data from Firebase database. Main idea is using the data from Firebase, I am trying to build CSS cards for each submission from a form.

During form submission, User chooses which category it belongs to and specific Image should be displayed in CSS card.

As the CSS cards are dynamically created, the entire HTML code is built using JS.

First this is the code for fetching data from Firebase and calling the function to create the CSS card.

```js
let reference = firebase.database().ref("data-block");
reference.on("value",gotData);
```

Now check the function for creating the CSS card.

```js
function gotData(data) {
    let x = data.val();
    let keys = Object.keys(x);
    console.log(keys.length);
    var q = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {

        let a = keys[i];

        let title_a = expens[a].Entry;
        let category_a = expens[a].Category;

        console.log(title_a, category_a);

        let expense = document.querySelector(".card-list");

        expense.innerHTML += `

        <article class="card">
        <header class="card-header">

        <h2>${title_a} </h2>
        </header>

        <div class="card-author">
            <a class="author-avatar" href="#">
                <img id="x" src=""/>
            </a>

            <svg class="half-circle" viewBox="0 0 106 57">
                <path d="M102 4c0 27.1-21.9 49-49 49S4 31.1 4 4"></path>
            </svg>

            <div class="author-name">
                <div class="author-name-prefix">Author</div>
                ${category_a}
            </div>

        
        </article>
        
    `;
    }
}
```

As you can see src of the image is not declared because I couldn't figure out how to assign different images based on Category fetched from Database

I have 3 images like

```
shopping.png
food.png
learn.png
```

Help me out on how to assign src for the image tag dynamically based on data from Firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function getImageByCategory(category) {
  if (category == 'shopping') {
    return '<img src="shopping.png" />';
  } else if (category == 'food') {
    return '<img src="food.png" />'
  } else if (category == 'learn') {
    return '<img src="learn.png" />'
  }
}

`
<a class="author-avatar" href="#">
  ${getImageCategory(category_a)}
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the values of the categories you could create an object that will translate those category values into the image names.

Try this (changing categoryA, categoryB, and categoryC into the values being returned as category_a):

```
...
    let category_a=expens[a].Category;
    
    const IMAGE {
        categoryA: 'shopping.png',
        categoryB: 'food.png'.
        categoryC: 'learn.png'
    }

    console.log(title_a,category_a);
    
    let expense=document.querySelector(".card-list");
    
    expense.innerHTML+= `

        <article class="card">
        <header class="card-header">

        <h2>${title_a} </h2>
        </header>

        <div class="card-author">
            <a class="author-avatar" href="#">
                <img id="x" src=${IMAGE[category_a]}/>
            </a>
...
```